# Create Shopware order with article number instead of ID?

Tags: salesforce, integration, shopware

I'm from salesforce side and develop an integration with shopware. I need to create orders. Can I use the article number of shopware as identifier instead of the ID, as I don't have this in SF currently? Otherwise I would need an additional integration.

Comment: is it about Shopware 6 or Shopware 5?

Comment: Hello Michel, it's Shopware 5. I tested a bit around, but it seems there is no way without the ID. So I will create another integration first to sync the Id into SF.

Comment: sorry that is not possible out of the box, if I see that correctly. the relation ship between the order detail position and the product variant is based on the IDs. 
If you want to resolve the product from its number, you may need a custom extension of the `\Shopware\Components\Api\Resource\Order::prepareCreateOrderDetailsData` method